# How can I set a floating point timeout value for a read command in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a script where I must take input from the user with a timeout of less than a second (0.03). I use the read command with the option -t which works with floating point values on linux bash (at least on arch and debian). However the macOS version of bash's read builtin only works with integer values.

original command:

```
read -sn3 -t 0.03 INPUT
```

I tried using the timeout command but of course it does not work with shell builtins. I also tried sending an input via a fifo after the desired amout of time to stop the read but I couldnt figure out how to read from the file and from stdin at the same time.

EDIT:

here is the error returned by read:

> bash: read: 0.03: invalid timeout specification

Comment: This is working fine for me, but it's a shell-based `read` so the overhead of your tools may be shooting your timing in the foot. FWIW, my test was simplistic - `for t in 1 2 3 4 5; do date;  read -sn3 -t $timout INPUT; done` with various values for the `$timout`

Comment: You tried it with a floating point timeout value on macOS' bash ?

Comment: Does your system allow sub-second `sleep`s?

Comment: with the last version of bash it does, but not with the default version on macOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had the same issue. Try to launch these commands

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.57(1)-release

$ bash -c 'echo $BASH_VERSION'
5.0.7(1)-release
```

As you see, there are two versions of the bash shell. Launch your script with this syntax

```
bash your-script-path
```

and not just

```
your-script-path
```

This way you will use the new bash, supporting the **read** command with decimal timeout. 
If you have a different situation, eg. an older bash, install a newer one with homebrew

Comment: Apparently apple does not update bash anymore because of a licence issue. Im going to install the last version with brew and try. Anyway, thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Fofoyoyo or use the pre-installed zsh. For most things it is compatible with bash and has even more features.

Comment: @Socowi there is no timeout option for read on zsh, also the rest of the script uses bash specific syntax. EDIT: my bad, there is indeed a timeout option

Comment: It's a bash version issue, since read is a builtin command and not a real program. Did you try with brew?

Comment: I just did, and it works. Still it's annoying to have to manually install the last version.